# replace empty input with 0 and accept only numbers in input type text

Tags: javascript

I'm a JS learner. I want to display input values in each line (and it's done) but I want to prevent displaying empty values as empty space and replace them with "0". Also I want to force only numbers in the input. Can anyone help me?

```
   <input type="text" id="user-input" onfocus =   "this.value =''">
    <button id="submit" onclick="addTo()">Submit</button>
    <p class="demo"></p>
```

```
  const myArr = []; 

   
  function addTo() { 
     myArr.push(document.getElementById("user-input").value); 
     if(myArr.value = "") {
        myArr.value = 0;
     }
    document.querySelector(".demo").innerHTML = myArr.join("<br />")
  }
```

Comment: does it really need to be an input of type text? Maybe you would be better off using a input of type number...
You are checking if the input's value is empty after you add it to the array. I think you should do it before if your goal is to add a 0 to the array whenever the input is empty

Comment: also, using `innerHTML` maybe be dangerous, because it means people could add their own html (or even javascript) to your page (by entering it in the input). This way they could get some data that should be kept private, bring your website down, ...

Comment: I change the input type number and it works. But I still get empty "space" when the input is "empty" instead of "zero". As for your second comment, thanks for the warning but I'm just learning JS on my own and I try out different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you wrote you on the comments, you should change the input to `type="number`.
Then you must check if the input value in empty **before** adding it to the array.

Take a look at the example i create for you. There are other ways to do this, but i wanted to stay true to your original idea. i hope it helps you...

```js
let myArr = [];

function addTo() {
  const enteredValue = document.getElementById("user-input").value;
  const readyValue = enteredValue === '' ? 0 : enteredValue;
  myArr.push(readyValue);

  document.querySelector(".demo").innerHTML = myArr.join("<br />")
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="user-input" onfocus="this.value =''">
<button id="submit" onclick="addTo()">Submit</button>
<p class="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Tx a lot. It's difficult to learn on my own. And sometimes it's hard to research the issue that is similar and I don't use very advanced methods and syntax and no frameworks yet. Some people downgrade the question at the very start.

Comment: i know that feeling. on youtube there are a lot of great channels to learn JS. i really like The Coding Train and the Coding Garden (not sure if it still exists), but there are a lot of others, like Traversy Media and FreeCodeCamp

Answer (score 1):

No need for any javascript you can solve both by

```
<input type="number" placeholder="0">
```

Granted the placeholder will only show "0" on screen but will return blank as value

Comment: That's not what I wanted achieve but thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).